# Docker ADD and COPY not honored in Dockerfile

Tags: apache, docker

When I try to build the following Dockerfile, the ADD and COPY steps do nothing:

```
# Use an official Apache runtime as a parent image
FROM amd64/httpd

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR  /usr/local/apache2

# Copy the following contents into the container
ADD ./httpd.conf {$workdir}/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./Projects/RavensHomeSupport/build/* {$workdir}/htdocs/Test/

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME RavensHomeWeb
```

I run the following build command:

```
docker build -t ravenshome --rm --no-cache .
```

and when I check the contents of the `Test` directory in the running container, none of the data that I expected has been copied across to the container. The output of the build command is here.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.444MB
Step 1/6 : FROM amd64/httpd
 ---> 19459a872194
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR  /usr/local/apache2
 ---> Running in 192cb44f767e
Removing intermediate container 192cb44f767e
 ---> d9816ea17258
Step 3/6 : ADD ./httpd.conf {$workdir}/conf/
 ---> 19f48db970bb
Step 4/6 : COPY ./Projects/RavensHomeSupport/build/ {$workdir}/htdocs/Test/
 ---> d93939218c2b
Step 5/6 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 43b9e9297f60
Removing intermediate container 43b9e9297f60
 ---> 3b994be07747
Step 6/6 : ENV NAME RavensHomeWeb
 ---> Running in a64bccaf81c8
Removing intermediate container a64bccaf81c8
 ---> 9217c242868c
Successfully built 9217c242868c
Successfully tagged ravenshome:latest
```

I start the container with the following command:

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:80 --name ravenshome ravenshome
```

When I examine the problem directory in the container with the following command:

```
docker exec ravenshome ls -a /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

I get the following result:

```
.
..
index.html
```

As you can see, all that was there is the contents of the default image, not the additional content that I expected.
Similarly, my customized version of `httpd.conf` is not copied to the new container.
I have read several posts that suggest that the problem is due to using volumes, but I am not doing so, nor do I have a `.dockerignore` file.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see if you look around a little more?  Is there perhaps a `/usr/local/apache2/{}/conf` directory?

Comment: @David Maze - Yes there is but I have been unable to find anything about what this directory is for,

Answer (score 1):

`$workdir` isn't a defined environment variable, so it expands to an empty string.  `$variable` inside curly braces isn't special syntax at all; it expands to the variable expansion, inside curly braces.  The net result of this is that these two lines:

```
WORKDIR  /usr/local/apache2
ADD ./httpd.conf {$workdir}/conf/httpd.conf
```

copy content into a directory `/usr/local/apache2/{}/conf/http.conf` -- nothing is inside the curly braces, and the curly braces themselves are interpreted as a directory relative to the current working directory.

You don't need an environment variable here at all; you can just `COPY` to the current `WORKDIR`

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2
ADD ./httpd.conf ./conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./Projects/RavensHomeSupport/build/* ./htdocs/Test/
```

See also [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) in the `docker-compose.yml` documentation for the allowed forms; you're probably thinking of `${variable}` syntax (dollars *outside* the curly braces).

Comment: If I try to use the current WORKDIR, the build runs without complaint, but when I try to run the container, it exits immediately without any visible reason.